# How to create image from NSDATA to UIIMAGE asynchronously

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow speed while converting NSDATA to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965283/slow-speed-while-converting-nsdata-to-uiimage)

I have 10 images, each is 2Mb in size stored in a dictionary. I wish to show the images on a scroll view one at a time.
Converting the 2Mb image from NSData to UIImage takes a noticable amount of time, making the scrolling appear to hang.

How can I create an image from NSData to UIImage asynchronously and add them onto the Image view?

Currently I am using the following code, but the performance is not very good:

```
id oo = [str valueForKey:@"aa"];
[img setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:oo]];
```

Comment: You were given an answer as to how to do this in the answer to your previous question, linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Do the image loading in a separate thread (not the main thread), and then when the image has loaded, use the main thread to present it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not preload your dictionary?  Store UIImage objects instead of NSData?  Other than that, you could display a low-res thumbnail (which you could store separately) of each image, and load the full image in the background.